# TypeScript: How to import multiple variables?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React app that's using TypeScript. My directory structure looks like this:

- App.tsx
- /pages

  - Page1.tsx

The contents of `Page1.tsx` look like this:

**Page1.tsx**

```
class PageParams {
  constructor() {
    
  }
}

class Page1 {
  constructor(props: any) {
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
}
```

I want to use both types in App.tsx. I know that I can only export *one* type from a file using something like `export default Page1;`. However, I would really like to keep my types in one file.

How can I access both variables from App.tsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can only use one `export default` statement, that's because by definition there's only one default export. However, you can export as many variables as you like with the `export` keyword.
In your example:

```
export class PageParams {
  constructor() {
    
  }
}

export class Page1 {
  constructor(props: any) {
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
}
```

Then, when importing you write this (notice the curly braces):

```
import { PageParams, Page1 } from '...'
```